# This javascript code doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <script>
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.view-content img')
images.forEach(item => {
  const src = item.getAttribute('data-original');
  const newSrc = 'https://example.com' + src;
  item.setAttribute('src', newSrc);
})
</script>
```

This code changes

`<img src="/data/img/img_01.png">` to

`<img src="https://example.com/data/img/img_01.png">`

as you can see.
but this code doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11.
How can i make this code work in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the **arrow functions** nor the **forEach()** method are compatible in IE11. You need to rewrite the above using *ES5* like this:

```
<script>
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.view-content img');

    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        let src = images[i].getAttribute('data-original');
        let newSrc = 'https://example.com' + src;
        images[i].setAttribute('src', newSrc);
    }
</script>
```

---

Or if you prefer using ES6 to write your JavaScript, you can use a toolchain like [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/repl) to compile your JavaScript ES6 to JavaScript ES5 on production.